# Node js application on AWS on windows instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I want to deploy my node js application on aws. I have created account and also launched the instance. Install node and copied my code to the aws account. I have created an windows instance not a linux/ubuntu instance. 
I am able to execute the node application on aws instance after logging using RDP.
Now how to access the same application deployed on the AWS from outside the AWS.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your Node Js application is web application or desktop application? Describe a bit about how did you accessed your application

Comment: my application is a web application. I am accessing the application using <public dns>:<port number>. port number is what I have specified in the node application.

Comment: Ok, in that case I believe the configuration of security group is the problem. Security group should have your port (the one on which node application listens to) accessible from outside world.

Comment: I have added the port 5000-5500 in custom TCP Rule everywhere in security group. and specified port 5000 where my application is listening. then also it is not working. I have added image above for my security group.

Comment: Ok. Can you enable flowlogs on your VPC, hit a request and  and share the flow logs across?

Comment: I m new to aws. I tried to create flowlogs, hit request but could not able to get the flow logs to share. If you can help a bit.

Comment: On Admin console, select "network & content delivery", then select "VPC"

Comment: Once you select the VPC on which your server is created, at the bottom of the page, you see four tabs namely description, Cidr blocks, flow logs and tags.    Upon selection of flow logs tab, click create flow log, please make sure 1. Filter is marked for "all" 2. Destination is pointing to S3 bucket.

Comment: I am using the free tier. will it work or it need paid account? see the image attached.

Comment: I don't think charges will be applied if you just enable  flowlogs,  can you please share the S3 bucket URL? I. Using my mobile and not able to access the logs

Comment: thanks for the information. I had terminated the instance and recreated it. I had turned off the firewall  and now I can access the node application from internet also. is it necessary to turned off the firewall to access the services.??

Comment: Ah..Ideally, you should not  turn off the firewall. Instead you should open the port your application listens to. In this case 5000. Also make sure you disable flow logs and delete S3 bucket which contains flow logs.

Comment: I got another way. I created Inbound rule and added the port number in firewall settings. Now I am able to access the node app without compromising the firewall.